# Similarity score in 3-dimensional data

Tags: python, neural-network

We have data that measures the location of a needle on a machine that does repetitive tasks (3-dimensions, x and y, over time). The motion of the needle is unpredictable, and we would like to model the most likely paths.

Originally, we have tried neural networks to make predictions. However, I have discovered that generally, the first dozen datapoints predict very well the direction in the future.

Using a historical dataset of 4000+ runs of these "potential paths", is there a way to iterate through all the 3d plots to find the closest sample?

We use python, but are open to other languages.

Comment: Why not just train an svm or something similar on those initial datapoints? Alternatively, Euclidean distance is something to look at. You would build a vector out of the first few datapoints of your paths, and then calculate distances.